# Declare function in taglib that has an inner class in the signature

Tags: java, jsp, taglib

Let's say I want to declare a function that has this java signature:

```
public static String getStatusString(ArticleAndStatus aas) {
    //...
}
```

and that `ArticleAndStatus` is an inner class of `org.example.Outer`.

How would I declare it in a taglib? These both fail:

```
   <function>
       ...
       <function-signature>java.lang.String
       getStatusString(org.example.Outer.ArticleAndStatus)
       ...
   </function>
```

```
   <function>
       ...
       <function-signature>java.lang.String
       getStatusString(org.example.Outer$ArticleAndStatus)
       ...
   </function>
```

Comment: post the code for the definition of Outer and how you defined ArticleAndStatus inside it. 

Just going on what I see atm, I suspect you didnt make the inner class public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue using a public static inner class.  I would say the syntax is the dot.  It may be a bug in here `org.apache.jasper.compiler.`

Comment: What was the resolution? That a bug was determined?

Answer (score 1):

`org.example.Outer.ArticleAndStatus`

Comment: Doesn't work:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6300: The class org.example.Outer.ArticleAndStatus specified in the method signature in TLD for the function adverse:getStatusString cannot be found. org.example.Outer.ArticleAndStatus

Comment: most likely org.example.Outer.ArticleAndStatus is not public. But there is too little to go on from the question to say for sure tho.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just create a dummy interface which you make your inner-class implement, and give it as the method parameter ?